# Celery Canvas not executing callback jobs

Tags: python-3.x, celery

I'm trying to create a multi-level Celery jobs canvas using the following code:

```py
job = chain(chord(group(job_list),
                      update_job_status.si(job_id_list, success=True).on_error(
                          update_job_status.si(job_id_list, success=False))),
                final_follow_up_job.si(job_id_list))
job.apply_async()
```

But the final level of jobs (`update_job_status`, `final_follow_up_job`) aren't getting called. No errors in the `job_list` jobs.

Python v3.9, Celery v5.1.2